# Using colon (:) operator to create DataFrame slices via a function call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to define a function which returns an index into a DataFrame. For example, I have

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'a', 'b'], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[1.1, 2.2 ,3.3]})
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

I can then slice into the DataFrame via `df.loc['a',1]` or `df.loc['a',:]` which will return the values in `C` matching the conditions on the index `A` and `B`. In the first case, I would get one value, in the second case two.

Instead of explicitly writing the index each time, I would like to define a function which generates this automatically. My pseudo function (which does not work) could be,

```py
def func(df, a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = ':'
    return df.loc[a,b]
```

With this, I would like to be able to do something like `func(df, 'a', 1)` and `func(df, 'a', None)` to get the same as if directly calling `df.loc['a',1]` or `df.loc['a',:]` respectively.

As I have multiple levels in my index, it would be very useful to have a way of defining the `:` operator if the argument passed to the function is `None`.

---

**Update:**
I have quite a few levels in the index, i.e. that I would like to avoid writing an `if` statement for every possible combination of `None`'s which I could have. For example, assume I have four levels in the index. It would be great to do something like,

```py
# Does not work
def func(df, a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if b is None:
        b = ':'
    if c is None:
        c = ':'
    if d is None:
        d = ':'
    return df.loc[a,b,c,d]
```

instead of writing an if statement for every combination of `None` in the arguments (7 in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `':'` as a string to `df.loc` with your current function. Something like this should get around the problem:

```
def func(df, a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = slice(None)
    return df.loc[a, b]
```

My understanding is that using `slice(None)` here is equivalent to passing `:`. I've only tested on your dummy dataset though so will be worth testing on your real data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, as I have quite a few levels in my index, I don't want to explicitly define each possible combination `None`s in `if` statements.

Comment: Wonderful! This is what I was looking for :)